# Получение новых новостей (постов) из json

Tags: веб-программирование, json, ios, objective-c, ios7

Есть, например, сайт, который отдает список постов (заголовок, дату, картинку и ИД поста) в формате json (например: *http://siteexample.com/apisite/pic.php?task=1&post=200* (здесь мы получим 200 новых/последних новостей). Распарсить не составит проблем (очень простой json). Но нужно получать новые посты/новости (offset`ов и разных примочек получения нет, только как в примере выше). Как правильно сделать, т.е. интересует не код, а алгоритм. Направьте на путь истинный. Спасибо.

Comment: Ссылка которую Вы привели не работает в том смысле что по ней не отдается JSON

Comment: Это ссылка просто пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый пост как Вы упомянули содержит некий id по которому его можно уникально идентифицировать. При парсе нового JSON'а проверяйте есть ли конкретное значение уже в базе. Если да, идете мимо, если нет - добавляете в базу и рефрешите вью на которую Вы выводите данные. Если id поста не является автоинкрементным, то чтобы иметь порядок постов, заведите это поле у сущности в которой Вы храните эти данные. При парсинге присваивайте новым сущностям автоинкрементное значение. Таким образом Вы будете иметь возможность отсортировать данные и иметь номер последнего поста по которому можно проверять данные при вхождении.

Comment: Да, там есть айди. И он инкрементируется, например: "ID":230647, "ID":230538. т.е. сортировка по убыванию постов.
В принципе все логично. Можно в одно из полей/столбец кордаты, добавлять этот айди. 
Алгоритм получается таков:
1. При повторном запуске приложения, брать из базы последний айди поста (который добавленный).
2. Добавлять посты (объекты json-дикшинари) в массив до тех пор пока не встретим пост с последним айди взятый из базы.
3. Добавить эти объекты в базу уже и так в отсортированном виде.

Как-то так. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы все верно описали. На здоровье!